# Actionscript - Player.IO : Some information?

Tags: actionscript-3, debugging, web-applications, webserver, package

So after i'm almost finishing a multiplayer game (that worked locally using a player.io server debugged in visual studio C#) i was wondering what will/should do when i want to add this game online, to my website?

- Do I need a server? (I think they cost a lot)
- Should I upload the player.io files in my website too?
- How will I debug my player.io server?

Answer (score 0):

upload your dll using the backoffice and host your swf by yourself and evrything will be fine :)

Comment: The link to the gamesnet backoffice has been moderated/deleted.